# Prevent external program from writing into a file, without error appearing in the external program

Tags: c++, file-io, windows-xp, exe, popen

We have an external program (20 years old .exe; we don't have the source code) that reads input from a file (for example "input.txt") and writes results into another (for example "output.txt"). The program also prints some output to the console. I want to execute this program millions of times with various input files and do something with the results. I am using C++ for this.

Currently I have written a program, which
1) writes an input file,
2) executes the external program with popen(), and
3) reads the results from the console output.

However, file operations are not very fast and I would like to prevent the program from writing the output file, because it is large compared to the console output and I only need the information that is printed to the console. However, if the external program is unable to open the output file for writing, execution will fail. Is there some way to fake this, so that the external program would think it is writing a file but actually doesn't? The program still has to access hard drive to read input files. I would prefer a solution that functions under Windows XP.

Comment: Isn't there s.th. similar as `/dev/null` under windoze?

Comment: @g-makulik: Yes there is `NUL` but IIRC it only works with stream redirections (ie. console output): I don't think you can symlink a file to `NUL` (assuming NTFS, of course, FAT doesn't have symlinks at all) like we do on *nix.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search in google:

http://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/
RAM Disk for Windows XP, 2003, 2008, Vista, 7 and 8.

I have nothing to do with this project. This is not an AD. I remember during DOS times RAM drives were popular. It seems that they have not died out completely. You might try to use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You may not fake the writing process (to a file) but make it faster . 
unix offers tmpfs for this and Windows have some RamDisk solutions.